# Log4j2 custom log level filtering to different files

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

This is my log4j properties file

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
<CustomLevels>
    <CustomLevel name="ANALYTICS" intLevel="50" />
</CustomLevels>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-7level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName=abc.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %5p - %c - %m%n" />
    </File>
    <File name="analyticsFile" fileName="efg.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %5p - %c - %m%n" />
    </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="TRACE">
        <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" level="TRACE" />
        <AppenderRef ref="analyticsFile" level="ANALYTICS" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here, I've created a custom log level (ANALYTICS = 50) which has a value lower than the FATAL (100) level. There are 2 files which will collect all my logs. efg.log collects all the ANALYTICS level logs which is currently working. abc.log is collecting all the logs along with ANALYTICS log. I must avoid writing of ANALYTICS logs inside abc.log. abc.log should collect all logs other than ANALYTICS log.

What is the change required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threshold filter would help in this case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">

    <CustomLevels>
        <CustomLevel name="ANALYTICS" intLevel="50" />
    </CustomLevels>

    <Appenders>

        <File name="ANALYTICSFILE" fileName="logs/analytics.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %5p - %c - %m%n" />
        </File>

        <File name="FILE" fileName="logs/app.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss dd.mm} [%t] [%-5level] %logger{36} - %msg %n" />
            <Filters>
                <!--Deny message logged under Analytics log level-->
                <ThresholdFilter level="ANALYTICS"  onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            </Filters>
        </File>

        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>


    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" level="TRACE"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="ANALYTICSFILE" level="ANALYTICS"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```